# Hide Ant Design RangePicker Ok button

Tags: antd

Is there any way to hidden ok button in RangePicker, When the minute is selected, it will automatically jump to the next one。 [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-hide-rangepicker-ok-button-g9hn7p?file=/demo.js)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH3ZH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below in index.css file?

```css
    .ant-picker-ok {
      display: none !important;
    }
```